# Delete Cache-Control metadata from S3 using boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have a lot of s3 objects with Cache-Control metadata. The containing s3 bucket is being used by CloudFront and not all the objects are using the Cache-Control metadata. So, I want to delete the Cache-Control metadata using a script:

```
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('name')
for summary in bucket.objects.all():
        target_object = summary.Object()
        if target_object.cache_control != "":
                # delete cache control
```

I only found how to replace the value but not how to delete the metadata value. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: I think you need to `CopyObject()` to object to itself, but provide different meta-data. So, you are effectively making a new object (with the same Key) that has less meta-data.

Comment: I tried that too but the metadata key has an empty dict. Do you know how to get the current metadata?

Comment: The linked answer suggests: "Retrieve the original metadata with `head_object(Key=src_key, Bucket=src_bucket)`"

Comment: The problem is that when I call head_object the metadata is empty, look at this part of the response:

{ 'CacheControl': 'max-age=604800', 'ContentType': 'binary/octet-stream', 'Metadata': {}}